# Seemingly same code doesn't give the same results

Tags: c++, winapi

In my class I wrote the following code to deal with the gray area of the window. I try and not deal with the frames since the frames change styles sometimes and it causes unexpected sizing behavior. The expected behavior is that it return the topmost leftmost pixel of gray for the window.

```
POINT Dialog::GetPosition ( void ) const
...
    RECT rcPos, rcFrame;
    SetRectEmpty(&rcFrame);
    AdjustWindowRectEx(&rcFrame, this->Style, FALSE, this->ExtendedStyle);
    GetWindowRect(this->Handle, &rcPos);
    OffsetRect(&rcPos, -rcFrame.left, -rcFrame.top);
    return reinterpret_cast<LPPOINT>(&rcPos)[0];
```

I was then optimizing my class and reduced the code to the following (which I *think* should work the same):

```
POINT Dialog::GetPosition ( void ) const
...
    RECT rcPos;
    GetWindowRect(this->Handle, &rcPos);
    AdjustWindowRectEx(&rcPos, this->Style, FALSE, this->ExtendedStyle);
    return reinterpret_cast<LPPOINT>(&rcPos)[0];
```

Unfortunately it doesn't, and I've no idea what's happening or why the two above are any different at all. I've gone through it on paper multiple times and I can't see why using two different rects and offsetting them is any different from applying the frame offset directly to the original rect.

Ideas?

Comment: Unrelated to your specific question, but both examples invoke [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)...

Comment: I don't see any Offsetting done in the second code when you return rcPos, which maybe the difference.

Comment: @ildjarn, the `return` is creating a pointer to a local variable but it's dereferencing it at the same time. Is that the undefined behavior you thought you saw, or is there something else?

Comment: @Mark : No, I was referring to dereferencing a `RECT*` as a `POINT*` – this is a violation of aliasing rules, no?

Comment: @ildjarn, it would be except that Microsoft explicitly designed `RECT` and `POINT` so that it would work.

Comment: @Mark : The _standard_ says it is UB, it just happens to work with VC++...

Comment: Changed it and got what looks like more optimized ASM output anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

Your signs are mixed up. The first example should produce negative numbers for `rcFrame.left` and `rcFrame.top` but you're subtracting them from the position, giving a positive offset. The second example should be correct.